# set 80% of background color of a div to one color

Tags: html, css

I have a div and background color is red. Now I'd like to make left 80% remain red, rest 20% on the right part to no color or transparent. Is it possible to alter css only without adding  more divs or changing the padding of the div? I'd like div to remain it's original size.

Comment: You can use gradients. [Here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) is a website that makes it easy for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: Set a background color which is 50% of the width of the window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541081/css-set-a-background-color-which-is-50-of-the-width-of-the-window)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
.myClass
{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%, rgba(41,137,216,0) 20%, rgba(255,48,48,1) 21%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,0)), color-stop(20%,rgba(41,137,216,0)), color-stop(21%,rgba(255,48,48,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,0) 20%,rgba(255,48,48,1) 21%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,0) 20%,rgba(255,48,48,1) 21%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,0) 20%,rgba(255,48,48,1) 21%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,0) 20%,rgba(255,48,48,1) 21%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you can set multiple background colors for one div, but you could try:

```
div.twocolorish {
background-color: blue;
border-left: 20px solid green;
}
```

This would only work if you didn't need text (or other) to go over the part with the green border

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use padding to achieve the partial coloring. A div can be colored in the background which makes the whole div to be colored with the given color. But you can use an outer div to achieve your desired result or use [css3pie](http://css3pie.com) to achieve your desired result (especially in IE 8 and below). It has gradient options also.

```
<div style="width:500px; height:400px; ">
   <div style="width:80%; height:100%; background-color:blue;">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The resource  was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
(index):6770 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ (index):6770
(index):6770 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).