# Background color needs to span only certain percentage of its element

Tags: css, angularjs

I have the following structure:

```
<li class="myclass" ng-class="myAngularClass">
  <div> div1
     <div> div2
     </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

The element `li` is of dynamic height and width. `"myAngularClass"` has a property `background-color: green`.

The background color is spanning the whole `li`, which covers all the `div`s in it. But i want the width of the background-color to be only 10% so that it spans only until div1. I have seen [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541081/css-set-a-background-color-which-is-50-of-the-width-of-the-window) link, but i dont have much flexibility for adding other tags. "myAngularClass" returns a string that evaluates to a class name and i wrote the background-color property in that class name so that the li has the proper background color.

In short, i'm looking for a way to have a back ground color(such as background-color-width) for an element but only to a certain length.

Please let me know if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over the `background-color` attribute but you can control gradients widths, so you can create a gradient which in fact is built of only one color:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,255,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 10%,rgba(0,255,0,0) 10%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */
```

For cross browser support you can use this tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#00ff00+0,00ff00+10,000000+100&1+0,1+10,0+11,0+100;Custom

You can also do this using images in the background.