# Split Background Centered Content

Tags: html, css, layout, background

I'm trying to do a full-width split background colour with a centered content area. However, the content does not line up and is always off when the screen is resized.

The max-width is 1200px of the centered content area, the parent divs are split 60%/40%. When you do the math it's 720px/480px and should match the above div.

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.site-content {
  clear: both;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.site-content,
.left_container >div,
.right_container>div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.left_container,
.right_container {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -100%;
  /*Fixes float height*/
}
.left_container >div,
.right_container>div {
  position: relative;
}
.left_container {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #ced7db;
}
.left_container > div {
  float: right;
  max-width: 720px;
}
.right_container {
  background-color: #999;
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
}
.right_container > div {
  max-width: 480px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="site-content">
    <h1>Heading<h2>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="introduction" >
<div class="left_container">
    <div>
        <h2>Left</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="right_container">
    <div>
        <h2>Right</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The desired outcome of this would be to have the heading area and content area aligned on the left and right edge, while the backgrounds extend to the end of the browser. I have tried using the gradient background method, the percentage width is still thrown off.

Comment: Here's a quick mockup with `flexbox`: https://jsfiddle.net/tduwy1vf/. Here's one using `display: table`: https://jsfiddle.net/tduwy1vf/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I tried modifying your mockup but can't seem to make the columns full width. Here's an visual mockup of what I'm going for: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5095783/split-bg-layout3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to do exactly what I wanted So I settled for the parent background gradient method. Example here:
[CSS: Set a background color which is 50% of the width of the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541081/css-set-a-background-color-which-is-50-of-the-width-of-the-window)