# How to add texture background from center of the browser?

Tags: html, css

**I have added a texture background image in html body part and it is repeating the whole body section, but I want this texture will be repeat half of the browser**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Background</title>
  <style>
    body{
      background:url('bg.png');
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[reference image - what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnUZx.png)

Comment: You can use 2 div with width: 50%?

Comment: `background-position:` ?

Comment: background-position with repeat will not help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541081/css-set-a-background-color-which-is-50-of-the-width-of-the-window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a pseudo-element on the body that is absolutely positioned.

It's 50% wide, 100% high and over 50%.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
body:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-25-25-1.jpg);
  z-index: -1;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Heading</h1>
```

Comment: but there is one problem. If I added some content in body part, content is hiding in texture part. How I will fixed it ?

Comment: Updated demo...just add `z-index:-1` to the pseudo-element.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PLfLW/1951/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="wrap">content area</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url('bg.png');
}
#background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

#wrap {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```