# Bootstrap Grid - vertical split within container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with aligning a container-fluid within bootstrap. I've attached a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve. The list items on the bottom left should align with the text at the top (which is contained in a container). The newsletter section on the bottom right (red background) should span the entire width from the center to the edge of the screen. The content within the newsletter section should also be aligned with the text at the top.

Here's what I currently have for the code at the bottom:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="footer" class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Consumers</li>
            <li>Sites</li>
            <li>Operators</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <div id="newsletter" class="col-md-6">
            <h4>Subscribe to our newsletter to receive the latest news about Poqeta </h4>
        </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

[bootstrap-grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Jcu.png)

Comment: Why are you using container-fluid exactly then? Just make it a container as well....

Comment: Try to put css and other part of the HTML you are using as well.

Comment: @reinder the reason I used container-fluid rather than container is to allow the right side to be full width. when I change container-fluid to container, the red background gets cut off within the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your footer in a div that you give a background that is half of the screen width, either using CSS gradients (if your only concern is modern browsers) or with absolutely positioning elements or images. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541081/css-set-a-background-color-which-is-50-of-the-width-of-the-window#8541575) for more information. Then within this "footer wrapper" you place a container, and within this container you define your columns. For each column you set the background color again. This will "overlay" the background color of the footer within the container.

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-8 left">
      left section, list items
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 newsletter">
      newsletter section
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.footer {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff 50%, #ff0000 50%);
}

.left {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.newsletter {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31renvue/) for an example, you may want write some CSS for mobile (depending on what breakpoint you use for column wrapping, -sm, -md or -lg)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

to

```
<div class="container">
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, when I use a "container" instead of "container-fluid", the right side (newsletter) is contained also, meaning the red background will not stretch to the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

To make background full page, try this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

You can make "padding: 0" on "container-fluid" or "container" to make it straight