# css percentage based background

Tags: html, css

How can I show a div with some text (which fills the div completely in width) and then show a background color which is only 40%, without obstructing the text.

The following is problematic because the text is within the inner div. I want it in the outer div so to speak.

```html
<div>
<div style="background-color:#EAFEE2; width:35%;"><span>This is a much longer text and takes up a lot of space</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gradiant background .

```
background:linear-gradient(90deg, #EAFEE2 40%, #FFFFFF 50%)
```

check this link for More information: [CSS: Set a background color which is 50% of the width of the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541081/css-set-a-background-color-which-is-50-of-the-width-of-the-window)

Answer (score 2):

You can make the inner DIV absolutely positioned, with a negative `z-index` and the desired width restriction as in the following snippet.

Note: The inner DIV is empty, the text is only in the outer DIV, not in the inner one)

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #EAFEE2;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner"></div>
This is a much longer text and takes up a lot of space
</div>
```