# Half Background color for div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I do this kind of design using CSS, the Half-background color for div?

[image]

Comment: Hey welcome to stack overflow.. We would like to help you, however the way this community operates is you try things first (an attempt) and than ask a question with your code supplied. Do some research and re post a question when you are more prepared .. Best of luck and welcome to SO.. You can achieve that sort of background with CSS properties this can get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541081/css-set-a-background-color-which-is-50-of-the-width-of-the-window

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div style="background-color: #007700; height: 200px; width: 100%"></div>
```

It's your green background... just put into that div - another three div-s with content, position them absolute and play with margins:

[Ready DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nsbo3v5y/1/). It maybe hard to understand, if you are novice in CSS, but google is powerful.

```
<div style="background-color: #007700; height: 200px; width: 100%">
   <div style="margin-left: 1%" class="bubu">1</div>
   <div style="margin-left: 33%" class="bubu">2</div>
   <div style="margin-left: 65%" class="bubu">3</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
 .bubu {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
```

*width could be set in pixels, if you need fixed width.

Comment: The problem with this solution is it completely wrecks the rest of your layout below these elements. Unless you have a hardcoded height (which I'd assume most won't want), any HTML under these elements gets overlapped. Still a valid solution, just more likely to cause other issues.

Answer (score 11):

Using [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) on the body element:

```css
html, body{ height:100% } 

body{
  background: linear-gradient(green 40%, transparent 40%) no-repeat;
}
```

Or using `box-shadow` (requires `px` units and not `%`) :

```css
html, body{ height:100%; margin:0; } 

body{
  box-shadow: 0 200px 0 -100px green inset;
}
```