# set background on the half of an element

Tags: html, css, background

I have a problem with a background that I don't know how to fix.

I want my background to start only at the middle of the frame.

Below, my code to set the background:

```
#video_player {
    background-image: url("http://94.23.46.98/img/bg-f.jpeg");
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

And the complete code of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/u4hpezon/

Comment: @Amessihel it is but for jsfiddle i need to put the full path

Comment: I already try but I think it is in my code there is a problem

Comment: Your fiddle seemingly shows an overly complicated design regarding the results. Although I can set up a simple fiddle as an example, it will be in your hands to start to rethink your CSS code. Avoid translations, !important tags for example except if you can't do it otherwise. You want to set the background at the bottom (left, middle, center?) of your video, without repeating it?

Comment: here the result I want 
http://94.23.46.98/img/result.png as you can see the background with the leaf start at the half of the player

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Half Background color for div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52573881/half-background-color-for-div)

Answer (score 0):

So, what you're trying to achieve needs more `div`. Below is a working example.

### C'est parti

1. **Create and style a container.**

   We create a `container` using a `div`. The container must fit the whole page, so let's do:

   ```
   min-height: 100vh;
   min-width: 100vw;
   ```

   to make it fit the page. Then, we want to position the `container`, because we will be using `absolute` positioning later on.
2. **Create a `div` to hold your content (text, image, whatever...)**

   This is our `.text-container` div. This `div` will as a container for your content. Then, make this `div` fill the entire page with:

   ```
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   ```

   and after that, let's position the inside `div`, `img`, `whatever`:

   ```
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   ```

   > See [A complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
3. **Create a `div` to hold the background**

   This is our `.background` `div`. We want this div to only fit half of the parent's height. This is the job of `height: 50vh;` After this, this `div` needs positioning.

   So let's do it:

   ```
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   ```
4. **Order the layers**

   You may experience problems with the order of the elements. Let's pre-fix that, just in case, using some `z-index: -1;` to be sure that the background stays in the background.

```css
body,
div {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.background {
  background: teal;
  height: 50vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.text-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  background: orange;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-container">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Text!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="background">

  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helped!