# Background color of specific area

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML, CSS and JavaScript and was wondering is there a way to add a background color to a certain part of an element?

```
  .box h3{
    color: #000;
    border: solid black;
    padding-left: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    }
```

To cut out the background color of the first lets say 250 pixels.

Comment: can you provide an image of the desired outcome?

Comment: as you describe it. Not really possible. But it is possible to achive what you want. Take a look at pseudo elements like before,after

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52575069/104380

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541081/css-set-a-background-color-which-is-50-of-the-width-of-the-window) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via gradient backgrounds. Example:

```
p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(9,9,121,1) 83%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 83%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}
```

1. Create an element with a fixed height
2. Define a gradient with 3 gradient stops
3. Calculate the gradient stop positions. In this case 83% of 300px is roughly 250px
4. 1st gradient stop is background color1
5. 2nd and 3rd gradient stop is color2

You need two gradient stops of color2 because otherwise you will get a linear transition between colours.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot!

Comment: Then would you kindly accept my answer as a solution ?