# HTML rowspan half a row

Tags: html, css

I am doing schedule in HTML, I already have a cell for every hour and day of the week (like a cell for monday 15:00 - 16:00, 16:00 - 17:00) but i came across a problem - what if I would want to schedule something that starts at 15:00 and ends on 16:30?

Idea I found is to mark every row with rowspan="2"(and those that takes 1.5hour will have rowspan="3") but there comes a problem that every odd cell is placed on right side of the table:

[image]

Code looks somewhat like that:

```css
    h2 {
      font-size:1em; 
      font-weight: 300;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      line-height:1em;
      padding-bottom: 2em;
      color: #FB667A;
    }

    h2 a {
      font-weight: 700;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #FB667A;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .taken {
        background-color:#ff0000;
    }

    .container th h1 {
      line-height:1em;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1em;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .container td {
          font-weight: normal;
          font-size: 1em;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
                box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
    }

    .container {
          text-align: left;
          overflow: hidden;
          width: 80%;
          margin: 0 auto;
      display: table;
      padding: 0 0 8em 0;
    }

    .container td, .container th {
          padding-bottom: 2%;
          padding-top: 2%;
      padding-left:2%;  
    }

    /* Background-color of the odd rows */
    .container tr:nth-child(odd) {
          background-color: #818181;
    }

    /* Background-color of the even rows */
    .container tr:nth-child(even) {
          background-color: #5f5f5f;
    }

    .container th {
          background-color: #323232;
    }

    .container tr:hover {
       background-color: #669999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
                box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
    }

    .container td:hover {
      background-color: #FFF842;
      color: #403E10;
      font-weight: bold;
  
      box-shadow: #7F7C21 -1px 1px, #7F7C21 -2px 2px, #7F7C21 -3px 3px, #7F7C21 -4px 4px, #7F7C21 -5px 5px, #7F7C21 -6px 6px;
      transform: translate3d(6px, -6px, 0);
  
      transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-duration: 0.4s;
          transition-property: all;
      transition-timing-function: ease;
    }

    @media (max-width: 800px) {
    .container td:nth-child(4),
    .container th:nth-child(4) { display: none; }
    }
    body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif
    }

    body, html {
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 1.8;
    }

    /* Full height image header */
    .bgimg-1 {
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-image: url("./photos/main2.jpg");
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    .w3-bar .w3-button {
        padding: 16px;
    }
```

```html
<table class="container">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><h1></h1></th>
                        <th><h1>Poniedziałek</h1></th>
                        <th><h1>Wtorek</h1></th>
                        <th><h1>Środa</h1></th>
                        <th><h1>Czwartek</h1></th>
                        <th><h1>Piątek</h1></th>
                        <th><h1>Sobota</h1></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2"><h1>15:00-16:00</h1></th>
                        <td rowspan="2">25:00-26:30</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">2242</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">9528</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">9528</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">6369</td>
                        <td rowspan="2" class="taken">25:00-26:00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2"><h1>16:00-17:00</h1></th>
                        <td rowspan="2">16:30-18:00</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">1714</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">01:31:50</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">9518</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">6369</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">01:31:50</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2"><h1>17:00-18:00</h1></th>
                        <td rowspan="2">10437</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">00:51:11</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">9518</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">6369</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">01:31:50</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">01:31:50</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2"><h1>18:00-19:00</h1></th>
                        <td rowspan="2">4161</td>
                        <td rowspan="2" class="taken">18:00-19:00</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">00:14:34</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">9518</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">6369</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">01:31:50</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2"><h1>19:00-10:00</h1></th>
                        <td rowspan="2">3654</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">1961</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">00:11:10</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">9518</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">6369</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">01:31:50</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2"><h1>10:00-11:00</h1></th>
                        <td rowspan="2">1001</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">4135</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">00:46:19</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">9518</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">6369</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">01:31:50</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Maybe like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541081/css-set-a-background-color-which-is-50-of-the-width-of-the-window

Comment: Might be out of the context but take a look at https://fullcalendar.io/ - I would go that way, rather than develop my own solution for that. What you will need to do here, is to transform the data so it will fit for that plugin - which is less work than do the whole schedule calendar by your own.

Comment: I already added CSS to snippet, just for the above comment - I don't know javascript to be honest, so my way to do it would be to just copy-paste the calendar, which I don't really like doing. I have seen that everything can be done with javascript, but I would highly appreciate any HTML/CSS way to do this task. It purpose is not full calendar, it's for my weekly schedule (it doesn't change a lot throughout the year)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS isn’t that important here, the main problem is the fact that the table structure you are creating is “faulty”.

If you put a table cell with `rowspan="2"` into one row, then there needs to be a “hole” in that place, in the next row - the corresponding table cell would have to be *left out*, otherwise, what space should that cell from the previous row “span into”?

And if *all* your cells from one row have `rowspan="2"`, then you need a *completely empty* row next, `<tr></tr>`.