# How to partially color an HTML element's background from bottom to top using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have managed to achieve what I'm trying to do from top to bottom using the following:

```css
/* I'm interested in filling with a solid color, but in order to partially fill the background, I seem to have to use a dummy gradient to make the color behave as an image */
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(blue, blue);
  background-size: 100% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Is there a way to fill the div from bottom to top so that the lower half is blue and the other half is white in this example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: Set a background color which is 50% of the width of the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541081/css-set-a-background-color-which-is-50-of-the-width-of-the-window)

Comment: @amirify thank you, basically yes I just had to change the angle of the gradient compared to what was given in the answer

Comment: @TylerH thank you, this is actually what works the best for my specific needs

Comment: @MikeKatz45 I converted my comment to an answer; please see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `background: blue` as the first property and change the linear-gradient to the values of `white, white` to invert the declaration.

```css
/* I'm interested in filling with a solid color, but in order to partially fill the background, I seem to have to use a dummy gradient to make the color behave as an image */
.test {
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white);
  background-size: 100% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

is this what you mean to do? You can change the `background-size: 100% 70%` to play with how far you want it to feed into the other space.

```css
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, blue);
  background-size: 100% 70%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, just without an actual gradient, key here is `background-position: bottom` to make it work nice and easy

Comment: oh sorry! thought we were keeping the gradient