# How to color text such that in black background it should be white, and in white bg text color should be black in css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Please check the below image.
I want to add white text color in black background
and black color to the text in white background.

```html
 <section className= "greeting">
    <div className="hello">
        <span>Hey There!</span>
     </div>
     <div className="color"></div>
  </section>
```

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

 .hello {
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   font-family: "Poppins", cursive;
   font-size: 10em;
   padding: 18vw 42vh;
   mix-blend-mode: difference;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
 }
.color {
   z-index: -100;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   pointer-events: none;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 50vw;
   background-color: #101010;
 }
```

I tried mix-blend-mode but it doesn't seem to work.

please help

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlMEX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution as per your Image

HTML Code

```
<div class="abWhiteAndBlack">
          <div className="hello">
            <span>Hey There!</span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.abWhiteAndBlack {
 background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, black 50%, blue 50%);
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.hello {
  color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

For other variations like horizontal or diagonal visit following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/47135366/18331761